# Using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit, calculate...

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{x^2-16}{x+4}$$

Since it doesn't tell us the limit.. Should i start with something like, claim $\lim f(x)=-6$ and then start the proof as usual? Thanks

Comment: This looks as if you really wanted the limit when $\,x\to -4\,$ and not when $\,x\to -2\,$ ...

Comment: Nah, because I have another practise question that is exactly the same thing, but with x→−4

Answer (score 1):

HINT: When $x\ne-4$,

$$\frac{x^2-16}{x+4}=x-4\;.$$

Comment: Is there a reason I cannot substitute the limit directly into the equation..?

Comment: @user74824: In this case you can. However, if you’re required to give an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, you’ll find it easier using $x-4$ than using the original fraction.

Comment: Yup...I remained fixed with the $\,x\to -4\,$ thing.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Amazing how one automatically reads it that way, isn’t it?

Comment: I tried letting L=x-4 but everything cancels out... Am I starting this the wrong way with |f(x)-L|<$\epsilon$..? 
$|\frac{x^2-16}{x+4}-(x-4)|<\epsilon$

Comment: @user74824: Why would you do that? The limit is a **number**. What number is it?

Comment: So it is -6 and I pretty much just do the proof as per usual..?

Comment: @user74824: That’s right. And since the fraction reduces to $x-4$ near $-2$, you’ll find that you can take $\delta=\epsilon$ as long as $\epsilon<2$.

Comment: Alright thanks.

Comment: @user74824: You’re welcome.

Comment: Indeed so, @Brian. Professional deformation, I'd call it, since if $\,x\to a\neq -4\,$ then the limit is boringly trivial. I think that's what caused me to misread.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$

Then $|f(x)-L|=|\frac{x^2-16}{x+4}-(-6)|=|x-4+6|=|x+2|.....$